# why do i get error when running Vitis 2021.2

Tags: linux, xilinx

My OS - RHEL 7.7
I installed Vitis 2021.2.
I source the settings64.sh file.

When I run ./vitis I get the following error:

Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tools/Xilinx/Vitis/2021.2/lib/lnx64.o/libxv_platform.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS

What is the problem and do I solve it?

Please help, I'm really stuck.

Thanks,
Alon

Comment: Your question is probably better suited for https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I believe you should post this question on Xilinx/AMD support forum: https://support.xilinx.com/s/?language=en_US, it takes some days to respond but you have Xilinx employees among others giving answers.

Comment: Actually, this question exists already in the Xilinx forum, and has an answer: https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006uvf00SAA/vitis-20212-has-some-java-library-issue?language=ja

Comment: Thanks, Fra93. I did this commands and now i get: 
sed: error while loading shared libraries: libxv_hsm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
tr: error while loading shared libraries: libxv_hsm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

vitis is opening but i cant build a platform